Are there any video/audio recordings of the launch of Sputnik 1?
I've been researching the launch of Sputnik 1, it is often renowned as the event that started the space age though I cannot find any confirmed videos of the launch or even a countdown/audio recording from the launch, I know that during the space race, the Soviet Union kept a lot of their advancements classified, though is anything of that sort available to the public now? If so, where can I find it?

I’m voting to close this question because space exploration is off-topic here, but on-topic on [space.se]

@Glorfindel so reopen the question and migrate it there, to Space Exploration

@ArchiveOfStars it's not un-common for off-topic questions to be migrated to a site where they are on-topic. Stack Exchange answers are for the benefit of future readers as well as the question authors; moving them to the right sight helps them to be more easily found in the future. There are almost 200 SE sites and many active users of Astronomy SE or Space SE and up joining and participating in the other one as well. You may also find History of Science and Math SE helpful as well.

You used the term video which normally implies television, or at least it did prior to the elimination of film in nearly all motion picture cameras. I am not aware of the Soviets televising early rocket launches, unlike U.S. launches which were sometimes televised. I realize that you probably are accepting both video and film as an answer, however if only film cameras were used to record the launch of Sputnik 1 then it is less likely that any audio of the launch exists, at least as far as the rocket itself, although perhaps there may be some available audio of the launch engineers.

@StevePemberton film or video would be helpful, if someone can find audio recordings from the launch engineers that would be great







In general, enter “sputnik 1 launch” and “sputnik 1 sound” into YouTube.  A lot of materials.

Documentaries quite often add sound effects when all that is available is film footage. The details on this particular YouTube video don't say much other than it is a Russian language film of the launch. However the music at the beginning along with having a narrator indicates that this is a Russian documentary. So no real way to know if the audio in the clip is from the actual Sputnik 1 launch or just generic launch audio that was added for the documentary.

@StevePemberton i did translate this video, it appears to be from a soviet news broadcast after the launch, translates to:
"And in the country that, under the leadership of the Communist Party, has achieved the greatest progress, it has succeeded in launching a satellite into orbit, penetrating beyond the Earth's atmosphere for the first time. On Thursday, the whole world was astonished by the successes of Soviet science and technology. Our rocket reached an unprecedented speed of about 8000 meters per second."

@ArchiveOfStars - Interesting, if the broadcast was made within a few days of the launch then it probably increases the chances that the audio was from the Sputnik launch. But still not 100% conclusive, as it would have required matching up a separate sound recording with the film. Certainly no technical problem doing that, but then that retains the possibility that a different launch audio was used. A live TV broadcast would be more conclusive. Also October 4th, 1957 was a Friday, so you might double check that part of the translation.

@StevePemberton it was translated by chatgpt soo yea I'll double check, also wasn't it launched on October 5th (at least local time not Moscow time)

@StevePemberton so I put the text through multiple translators and they all say Thursday, ill try getting the script from the video again

@ArchiveOfStars - Yes Sputnik was launched at 12:30 am on Saturday, October 5th local time in Kazakhstan, which was 22:30 Friday Moscow time, 19:30 Friday UTC.  Somewhat reminds me of the  Apollo 11 moonwalk, which is sometimes listed as occurring on Sunday, July 20th, 1969, other times Monday, July 21st. That's because it was early Monday morning UTC when Armstrong and Aldrin walked on the Moon, but it was Sunday evening Houston time.

@StevePemberton It's not "Thursday". The narrator starts saying "fourth" (well, he says "chet" (чет), which is the beginning of both "fourth" and "Thursday"), and then there's a jump in the audio, and it continues from a different part of the narration: "...day, the whole world...".

@ArchiveOfStars Please see my previous comment.

@Litho - great thanks. That would imply that the broadcast likely occurred no later than maybe a couple of weeks or so after the launch. It would be interesting to know more about the broadcast, and about other contemporary Russian news reports during the period immediately following the Sputnik launch.

@StevePemberton Not necessarily. It could have been "fourth of October 1957" (in Russian, you say the day before the month), so the broadcast could have been from some later year.

@StevePemberton sputnik 1 was said to have launched on 4 October 1957 at 19:28:34 UTC, in soviet Kazakhstan, the timezone was +5 UTC which is 1:28 am October 5th

@ArchiveOfStars - The local launch time is surprisingly hard to pin down. The closest I could find was on a NASA website which said only that it was “near midnight local time”. While all of Kazakhstan is now UTC +5, that is only as of this past March when eastern Kazakhstan changed from UTC +6 to UTC +5. And farther back western Kazakhstan was UTC +4, as shown in this 1957 National Geographic Map.

@ArchiveOfStars - the time zone map is in the lower right hand corner of the National Geographic map. I placed a red dot on a zoomed in section of the map where the Baikonur launch site is, it seems to be right on the line, and quite possibly was in the previous UTC +4 time zone in 1957.

@StevePemberton oh wow I think you're right, the other timezone maps of the ussr I was looking at must have been published later

Wow! This is where the discussion unfolded)

ayr - yes I suppose your answer got a bit hijacked. But we often are forced to view history through somewhat blurry articles and documentaries. Good enough I suppose, similar to looking through a slightly out of focus camera lens where you can see objects well enough to identify them. But it’s nice sometimes to turn the focusing ring just a little bit more and get a sharper picture. That’s what the discussion is about. Worth it I think for a pretty significant historic event in human history. But yeah
@ArchiveOfStars and I can delete the timezone comments now that we have hashed it out.

@StevePemberton you have a wonderful discussion that makes us look at the story from an additional angle, clarify some details, I think that watching the video and reading the comments will be useful for other people
